# URL Rewriting with / or not

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to fix this warning:

> Avoid use of file extensions wherever possible.... Consider URL rewriting as an effective and transparent means of creating appropriate URLs

I added to my .htaccess file this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Its working fine on example.com/page but Im getting an Internal Server Error on example.com/page/
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to allow an optional trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now / works but, the html page appears without styling (CSS etc).

Comment: For css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: <base href="/" /> Did the job very well.. Thanks anubhava!